# Looping through a list of tuples in a function that creates new columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Attempting to create a function that loops through a list of tuples and appends each new column to my original DataFrame. Currently, the function allows one tuple list at a time and I am having difficulty looping through all of them in the function that I have created. Below is what I have so far. Thanks for all the help!

```
def divide_two_cols(df,tuple_list):
         for x,y,z in tuple_list: 
                calc = df[x] /df[y]
                calc.replace(np.inf, 0, inplace=True)
                calc.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)
                df[str(z)] = calc
                return df

 tuple_list_2 = [('Total_Revenue', 'Spend', 'ROAS')]
 tuple_list_3 = [('Total_Revenue', 'Conversions_10D', 'AOS')]
 tuple_list_4 = [('Spend', 'Clicks', 'CPC')]
 tuple_list_5 = [('Conversions_10D', 'Impressions', 'conv_rate')]
 tuple_list_6 = [('Spend', 'Conversions_10D', 'CPA')]
 tuple_list_7 = [('Clicks', 'Impressions', 'CTR')]
```

Comment: How about converting them to series and add to the dataframe?

Comment: `divide_two_cols(df, tuple_list_2 + tuple_list_3 + tuple_list_4 + ...)` ?

Comment: @phi Unfortunately, when I add the tuples, only the first tuple is added into the new DataFrame. Is there something potentially wrong with my code?

Comment: @mad_ Would you be able to provide an example please? Thanks!

Comment: The line `return df` should have the same indent as the `for` loop.  Otherwise the `return` will be called after just one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def divide_two_cols(df,tuple_list):
     for x,y,z in tuple_list: 
            calc = df[x] /df[y]
            calc.replace(np.inf, 0, inplace=True)
            calc.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)
            df[str(z)] = calc
     return df

divide_two_cols(df, tuple_list_2 + tuple_list_3 + tuple_list_4 + ...)
```